# SBS 2008 Standard - Exchange 2007 fails to install

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

I've just re-installed onto a new server SBS 2008 Standard. Installation completes without incident but when it returns me to the desktop eventually; it tells me some installation steps failed.

Exchange 2007 didn't install. The Exchange setup logs show this:

```
[WARNING] An unexpected error has occurred and debug information is being generated: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
[04/10/2013 19:00:50] [1] [ERROR] Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

I'm trying to find a way to finish re-installation. All other services appear to functional. Anyone ever seen this before?